# Place div side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My HTML code is like below

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <ul>
        <div class="area" id="div_1">
            <li class="category" id="1">Hair</li>            
        </div>
        <div class="area" id="div_3">
            <li class="category" id="3">Skin Care</li>            
        </div>
        <div class="area" id="div_4">
            <li class="category" id="4">Makeup</li>            
        </div>
        <div class="area" id="div_5">
            <li class="category" id="5">Body Treatments</li>            
        </div>
        <div class="area" id="div_6">
            <li class="category" id="6">Sports Massage</li>            
        </div>
        <div class="area" id="div_7">
            <li class="category" id="7">Physiotherapy</li>            
        </div>
        <div class="area" id="div_8">
            <li class="category" id="8">Intensive Healing Pedicure</li>            
        </div>
        <div class="area" id="div_9">
            <li class="category" id="9">Pedicure Refresher</li>            
        </div>
        <div class="area" id="div_10">
            <li class="category" id="10">Therapeutic Pedicure</li>            
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS code is like below

```
.col-lg-4 > ul {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        width: 100%;
        display:flex;
    }

    .category {
        border:0;
        padding: 0;
        margin-right: 30px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
```

I would like to put div side by side with full width of their content and some margin right side.

I am getting output like below

[image]

I need output text will be in one line.

Comment: It seems like you have more markup than you actually need. What `divs` do you want side by side? Is this bootstrap?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? You must tell us or tag it so we know!

Comment: Thanks @disinfor. Yes, BootStrap is there.

Comment: Thanks @user1601324. Yes, BootStrap is there.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the bootstrap tag! You have wrong HTML also. You have `div` inside your `ul` . That is not allowed `ul` is only allowed `li` children. Please fix this too.

Comment: Could you please check bootstrap navbar i think you have expected like that

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I need output text will be in one line." Here's everything in one line. Basically, all you needed was `white-space: nowrap`. I removed the extra HTML of the `div`s wrapping each `li` since that was invalid HTML and wasn't necessary. If you need `div`s, put them inside the `li`s. I'd make them `span`s though.

```css
.col-lg-4>ul {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.category {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="col-lg-4">
  <ul>
    <li class="category" id="1">Hair</li>
    <li class="category" id="3">Skin Care</li>
    <li class="category" id="4">Makeup</li>
    <li class="category" id="5">Body Treatments</li>
    <li class="category" id="6">Sports Massage</li>
    <li class="category" id="7">Physiotherapy</li>
    <li class="category" id="8">Intensive Healing Pedicure</li>
    <li class="category" id="9">Pedicure Refresher</li>
    <li class="category" id="10">Therapeutic Pedicure</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a grid layout, content must be placed inside columns (.col and .col-*) and only columns may be the immediate children of rows (.row). Rows should be placed inside a .container or .container-fluid for proper padding and alignment.

```
  <div class="container">
        <!--Row with two equal columns-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">Column left</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">Column right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of col-lg-4 is only 25% of the page. The text is getting cramped because of this. You can change it to col-lg-12 to occupy the whole page.

```css
.col-lg-12>ul {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.category {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vishnu. Please check the image. I think you will get idea from there.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead,

First of all remove all `div` inside the ,

Then,add this style,

```
.col-lg-4 > ul {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin:0;
}

.category {
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

> **`white-space:nowrap` makes the  inline. More info about [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)**

> **All `<li>` makes inline by `display:inline-bock`. More info about [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)**

```css
.col-lg-4 > ul {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin:0;
}

.category {
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <ul>
      <li class="category" id="1">Hair</li>            
      <li class="category" id="3">Skin Care</li>           
      <li class="category" id="4">Makeup</li>            
      <li class="category" id="5">Body Treatments</li>            
      <li class="category" id="6">Sports Massage</li>            
      <li class="category" id="7">Physiotherapy</li>            
      <li class="category" id="8">Intensive Healing Pedicure</li>            
      <li class="category" id="9">Pedicure Refresher</li>            
      <li class="category" id="10">Therapeutic Pedicure</li>            
    </ul>
</div>
```